# SSL Certificate Errors With BrowserMob-Proxy on Firefox 50

Tags: firefox, ssl, browsermob-proxy

I am having trouble getting https requests to pass through BrowserMob-Proxy with Firefox 50.   However with Firefox ESR45.4 there is no such issue.

As a simple test I started BrowserMob-Proxy and created an instance on port 8088.

I then launched Firefox (This was done manually to verify it wasn't some with the automation scripts) and in settings set both the HTTP Proxy and SSL Proxy to localhost and port 8088.

Then goto https://www.google.com

Firefox ESR45.4 opens google without issue.
Firefox 50.x opens a "Your connection is not secure" page, and because of HSTS you cannot add an exception.

Am I overlooking something obvious, or has Mozilla finally broken Firefox to the point where you can't test with it anymore?